# Bootstrap collapse issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="navbar-header">  
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#MyNav">
         <span class="sr-only"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand">Jaso</a>
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MyNav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Protilio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">dontknow</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to make the button working like what is shown below, but the above code doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my code?

[collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlPLL.png)

Comment: I think you are missing the JS dependencies, but don't take my word. I'm just guessing that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the javascript included in your snippet. If you don't have them in your code, the collapse won't work. The html looks OK to me (same as my working example on my server).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I written down this in Codepen website. But I saw others works. They just included the '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ThanksI written down my code at Codepen website. I have already add this code, but it still doesn't work TAT.